# Getting the next hour in java

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp

Please provide the code getting next hour from database. For example I am getting a `timestamp`  from the database as:

```
    String sqlupdate = "select UploadedDate from CAF_Entry where Status='new' and Reference=0   order by UploadedDate limit 1";
    System.out.println("sql query"+sqlupdate);
    Statement stupdate = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsupdate = stupdate.executeQuery(sqlupdate);
    if(rsupdate.next())
    {
      date22=rsupdate.getTimestamp("UploadedDate");
      String stringdate=date22.toString();`
```

I am getting the date `2012-11-12 10:30:00`

How do I get the next hour, such as `2012-11-12 11:00:00`?

Comment: My advice: replace begging with code formatting.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik In my experience, 'begging' like this is more due to poor translation into the English language then it is because of any intended rudeness. A little understanding goes a long way.

Comment: @gbtimmon Begging is not a problem, but is redundant; I advised OP to replace a redundant aspect of his question with proper code formatting, which was clearly missing. I don't think code formatting rules vary between cultures. In that respect, we are all in the same culture: programmers :)

Answer (score 4):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(date22.getTime);
calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
```

After that you can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format the date to a String if you want it in that form.  `Calendar.getTime()` will return a `java.util.Date` object if you need one.

Answer (score 0):

```
String sqlupdate = "select UploadedDate from CAF_Entry where Status='new' and Reference=0   order by UploadedDate limit 1";
System.out.println("sql query"+sqlupdate);
Statement stupdate = con.createStatement();
ResultSet rsupdate = stupdate.executeQuery(sqlupdate);
if(rsupdate.next())
{
  DateTime date22=new DateTime(rsupdate.getTimestamp("UploadedDate").getTime()).plusHours(1);

  String stringdate=date22.toString();`
```

You'll need to use [joda-time](http://joda-time.sf.net), which you should be using as the JDK Date/Calendar clusterfsck is horrid.

Comment: importing joda-time for this would be using a chainsaw when a hand saw will suffice. There is no good reason to avoid Calendar here.

Comment: My general principle is to avoid Calendar/Date in Java precisely because, as noted, it is horrid, @gbtimmon, feel free to correct the code if you feel so strongly one way or the other about it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.setTimeInMillis(date22.getTime());
c.add(Calendar.HOUR, 1);
Date d = c.getTime();
```

Comment: That does not set the minutes and seconds to 0 as requested