# In Java how to add several hours to a date object considering the day light saving

Tags: java

Say in a DTO object I got its date field. Then adding several hours to that date and comparing it with current date time and return a boolean. Is there a way to do that by automatic handling day light saving stuff?

Comment: Have you tried using `Calendar`? Or [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/)? Or [Java 8's `java.time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)?

Comment: Duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2977316/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13495289/642706) and many more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The internal representation of the java date object is the number of milliseconds since EPOCH. This is regardless of daylight savings.

A human readable version of the local time, including the application of daylight savings, is merely a presentation of the value within the java date object.

So using a Calendar object to add a number of hours will work correctly regardless of whether daylight savings kicks in or not.